# Able to connect to postgres through hibernate but not able to get data by performing queries

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, docker

I have a docker container running a postgres db. The container also create a db, table and some test data. I also have a spring boot hibernate app that is able to connect to the db. I am however not able to perform any queries and get any data.

I have tested to see that I am connected to the correct db by changing the values in my application.properties file to a db name that does not exist - the java app works when I revert back to the correct db name.

I also supplied `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` in my application.properties file, this prints out the sql command. When I manually run this on the postgres, it returns data.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping("/hi/{id}")
    public String hi(@PathVariable("id") int index) {
        return "Hi " + accountService.get(index).getName();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public List<String> hey() {
        List<String> everyOne = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Account account : accountService.list()) {
            everyOne.add(account.getName());
        }
        return everyOne;
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public List<Account> list() {
       return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Account get(int index) {
        return accountRepository.getOne(index);
    }

}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> {

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Account() { }

    public Account(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Whilst the application is running, if I curl http://localhost:8080/all, I would have expected all the data in the Account table to be returned.

When I curl http://localhost:8080/hi/2, I get an error message saying

> 'avax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   com.something.models.Account with id 2'

As I am able to connect to the DB via hibernate and get data when manually running the sql commands that hibernate generates on psql command line, I am sure that I am just missing something simple here. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the reason why it was not working. My application is working fine as well the docker container that was running the postgres. The issue was that the account table was not in the postgres.

The reason why this was the case was because the tables and insert statements were not running on the db that I had created in postgres but were instead creating tables on the default db (postgres). I realised that when I have broken up by sql scripts in my docker-compose.yml file, for each .sql file, they were running whilst connected to 'postgres' db. By putting in a '\c db' in each of my scripts, this resolved all my issues.